You have attempted to set a value of type class java.util.ArrayList for parameter orgIds with expected type of class java.lang.Long
Problem:

        List<Long> orgIds = getOrgIds(chunkDataSync.getOrgId());

        parameters.put("orgIds", orgIds);

        List<DataSyncAbstract> commands = genericEAO.findByNamedQuery(
                "findChk", parameters);


    public <T> List<T> findByNamedQuery(String nameNamedQuery,
            Hashtable<?, ?> values) throws DataAccessException {
        Query query = null;
        try {
            query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(nameNamedQuery);
            if (values != null) {
                Set<?> keys = values.keySet();
                for (Object key : keys) {
                    if (key instanceof String) {
                        query.setParameter((String) key, values.get(key));
                    } else {
                        query.setParameter((Integer) key, values.get(key));
                

    }
                }
            }
        }

The orgIds values in debug:
[28, 16, 1309, 130903, 130906, 130909, 130910, 130911, 130912, 130913, 130914, 130915, 130916, 130917, 1401, 140101, 140102, 140104, 140105, 1402, 140201, 140202, 140203, 140205, 140207, 140208, 140209, 1501, 150102, 150103, 150105, 150106, 1502, 150202, 150203, 150205, 1503, 150301, 150302, 150303, 150304]
this is the namedQuery:
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "findChunkFullDataSync", query = "SELECT dataSync"
                + "  FROM FullDataSyncSGS dataSync"
                + " WHERE dataSync.isOrgHierarchyNode = :isOrg"
                + "   AND dataSync.id BETWEEN :initId AND :finalId"
                + "   AND (((1 = :hasOrg) AND (dataSync.operHierarchyNodeId IS NULL AND"
                + "       (dataSync.orgHierarchyNodeId IS NULL OR"
                + "       dataSync.orgHierarchyNodeId IN (:orgIds))))"
                + "    OR ((1 = :hasOper) AND (dataSync.orgHierarchyNodeId IS NULL AND"
                + "       dataSync.operHierarchyNodeId IN (:operIds))))"
                + " ORDER BY dataSync.id"),

atributo que recibe el List usando el IN
    @Column(name = "FDS_ORG_AREA_NODE_ID", unique = false, nullable = true, precision = 15)
    private Long orgHierarchyNodeId;

My Environment:
WL12
JDK: jdk1.8.0_121
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</vers

ion>

Tengo un problema con un query
MESSAGE : You have attempted to set a value of type class java.util.ArrayList for parameter orgIds with expected type of class java.lang.Long from query string SELECT dataSync  FROM FullDataSyncSGS dataSync WHERE dataSync.isOrgHierarchyNode = :isOrg   AND dataSync.id BETWEEN :initId AND :finalId   AND (((1 = :hasOrg) AND (dataSync.operHierarchyNodeId IS NULL AND       (dataSync.orgHierarchyNodeId IS NULL OR       dataSync.orgHierarchyNodeId IN (:orgIds))))    OR ((1 = :hasOper) AND (dataSync.orgHierarchyNodeId IS NULL AND       dataSync.operHierarchyNodeId IN (:operIds)))) ORDER BY dataSync.id.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a value of type class java.util.ArrayList for parameter orgIds with expected type of class java.lang.Long from query string SELECT dataSync  FROM FullDataSyncSGS dataSync WHERE dataSync.isOrgHierarchyNode = :isOrg   AND dataSync.id BETWEEN :initId AND :finalId   AND (((1 = :hasOrg) AND (dataSync.operHierarchyNodeId IS NULL AND       (dataSync.orgHierarchyNodeId IS NULL OR       dataSync.orgHierarchyNodeId IN (:orgIds))))    OR ((1 = :hasOper) AND (dataSync.orgHierarchyNodeId IS NULL AND       dataSync.operHierarchyNodeId IN (:operIds)))) ORDER BY dataSync.id.
